# Deploy firebase function with vpcConnector

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

The latest release of firebase (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v3.11.0) allows us to specify a VPC connector for a function to use.

```
export const redis = functions.runWith({
  vpcConnector: 'my-redis-connector',
  vpcConnectorEgressSettings: 'PRIVATE_RANGES_ONLY'
}).https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const client = redisLib.createClient(REDIS_PORT, REDIS_HOST)
  
  if (client.connected === true) {
    return res.status(200).send({redis: 'found'});
  } else {
    return res.status(404).send({ redis: 'not found'});
  }
})
```

After deploying the function using the firebase tools CLI `firebase deploy --only functions:redis`, I don't see the vpc connecter being created: [gcp-function-after-deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouh51.png)

Is there a different way of deploying the firebase function, besides using the gcloud that will take the vpcConnector?

Comment: If the Firebase CLI isn't working the way you expect, file an issue on GitHub along with the complete instructions on how to reproduce the issue  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools.

Comment: It seemed that I needed to first add the VPC connector to the cloud functions in GCP

Comment: You need to make sure you're on the latest version of the Firebase CLI in addition to `firebase-functions`. Support for `vpcConnector` was only added recently.

Answer (score 2):

The deployment of Firebase Function with this new feature does not create a VPC Connector, it only allows you to use an already existing VPC Connector in GCP by adding the new configuration to the function itself.

So in order to make it work you need to first create the VPC Connector in GCP using the instructions demonstrated in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access#creating_a_connector).